# Implementing `startCursor` and `endCursor` in Relay

Tags: relayjs

We have a graphql server not written in javascript, which we're trying to conform to the relay specification. `startCursor` and `endCursor` show up in a few examples but not in any official docs; based on my reading of https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/372 those fields are basically deprecated, but they do show up in some code still. Do we have to implement them:

- to be spec compliant?
- to work with existing clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not deprecated, and they do show up in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html). What that issue says is that you don't *have* to implement them if you don't want to use them directly in your app, because Relay is going to query the `cursor` for each edge in a connection automatically, and will use that when making requests during pagination.

Comment: They don't show up in https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm which I was considering somewhat more authoritative than the demo code you linked...

Comment: Yeah, and we probably won't add them to docs due to their non-critical nature. `PageInfo` has that shape because that's the way connections have historically worked at Facebook, but it's not to say that we should enshrine `startCursor` and `endCursor` in the spec forever.

Comment: @wincent have `startCursor` and `endCursor` become required in Relay Modern? Because I can't use the pagination container with a GraphQL API that does not support them

Comment: @Massimo yes they are required now, I checked the code in `relay-compiler` (RelayConnectionTransform.js specifically) `relay-runtime` and `react-relay`. These fields are specifically included on connection types and used in the runtime/React components.

Answer (score 3):

> to be spec compliant?

As you point out, these fields don't appear in the spec, so they must not be required to conform to the spec. I conclude this because I think that's the only conclusion any serious authors of a spec should want you to draw from the absence of something from their spec.

> to work with existing clients?

This, of course, is a different, more practical question :). The only client that I am aware of that uses the Connection spec is Relay, and Relay Modern requires these fields. Since these values are [used by the `PaginationContainer`](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/v1.5.0/packages/react-relay/modern/ReactRelayPaginationContainer.js#L526-L527), **the Relay Modern compiler requires them on any field [marked with the `@connection` directive](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/v1.5.0/packages/relay-compiler/handlers/connection/RelayConnectionTransform.js#L449-L463)**:

```
[END_CURSOR, HAS_NEXT_PAGE, HAS_PREV_PAGE, START_CURSOR].forEach(
  fieldName => {
    const pageInfoField = pageInfoType.getFields()[fieldName];
    invariant(
      pageInfoField &&
        SchemaUtils.getNullableType(pageInfoField.type) instanceof
          GraphQLScalarType,
      'RelayConnectionTransform: Expected type `%s` to have an ' +
        '%s field for which the type is an scalar in document `%s`.',
      pageInfo.type,
      fieldName,
      definitionName,
    );
  }
);
```

I never remember which of `endCursor` and `startCursor` corresponds to which pagination direction. Since they are not documented in the spec, you can look to [`graphql-relay-js`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/v0.5.4/src/connection/connection.js#L132-L152) for this information:

```
startCursor: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  description: 'When paginating backwards, the cursor to continue.'
},
endCursor: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  description: 'When paginating forwards, the cursor to continue.'
},
```